Why is there extra space between the image and the border? How do i remove it?
On the website I am making the aside that I am working on becomes larger when I add an image to it.
How do I remove the extra space on both sides of the image? I want the space to be around 20px as it is on the top of the image. I want the ratio to look like the image below with the picture in the aside.



aside {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: as;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#asideImg{
  display: block;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <a href="/Main.html"
      ><img src="/media/spöke.png" alt="logga" id="mainLogo"
    /></a>
    <h1 id="headerText">Min Halloweensida</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="/Pg2.html">Pg2</a>
    <a href="/Pg3.html">Pg3</a>
    <a href="/Pg4.html">Pg4</a>
  </nav>
  <aside><img src="https://placehold.co/400x400" alt="placeHolder" id="asideImg"></aside>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>



I have tried to set a fixed width to the aside but then the extra space moves to the gap instead.

Please add an image from https://placehold.co/ to the html to show the issue

I would recommend adding a border color to both your 'aside' and your 'img' tags. Also, you can inspect your component to see which styles are being applied to each elements.

When using display: flex; on a container, the container itself acts like a block element and takes up the entire available width.
You can use display: inline-flex; instead so it's only as wide as its contents, plus any margins, etc.  For example:


aside {
  display: inline-flex; /* <---- here */
  grid-area: as;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#asideImg{
  display: block;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <a href="/Main.html"
      ><img src="/media/spöke.png" alt="logga" id="mainLogo"
    /></a>
    <h1 id="headerText">Min Halloweensida</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <a href="/Pg2.html">Pg2</a>
    <a href="/Pg3.html">Pg3</a>
    <a href="/Pg4.html">Pg4</a>
  </nav>
  <aside><img src="https://placehold.co/400x400" alt="placeHolder" id="asideImg"></aside>
  <main>main</main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>



